# Finding the bottom left coordinate from a list of coordinates

Tags: c#

I have a list of coordinates (circle objects) and I'm trying to find the object on the bottom left.

(top left is 0,0)

I'm using the logic "bottom left circle is when X is minimum and Y is maximum" and it works in most cases;

[image]

But it fails in this case for example because the bottom left coordinate (circle) is not the one with smallest X value;

[image]

I use something like this and it mostly works;

```
private static int FindBottomLeftCircle(List<Circle> circles)
{
   return circles.IndexOf(circles.OrderBy(c => c.Center.Y).Reverse().Take(13).OrderBy(c => c.Center.X).First());
}
```

It works best if the bottom row has roughly 13 circles. But as you can see this approach has problems.

How can I reliably find the bottom left circle object?

Comment: You could just compute the distance from each circle center to the extreme bottom left of your overall bounding rectangle.  Shortest distance would be the bottom left circle?

Comment: Since you're passing the list of Circle objects, return the Circle instead of the index: `return circles.OrderByDescending(c => c.Center.Y).ThenBy(c => c.Center.X).First();`. Why `Take(13)`?

Comment: @Jimi it's just roughly the number of *columns* in the bottom row, in most of the cases. It of course fails when there are 9 columns as shown in the 2nd image of my question.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thank you, this seems to work in all the cases I could test so far. If you write it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Well, you're counting on an already defined center position, you don't need to know or care about the number of objects in the list. You already know the Circle(s) with the max Y: take the one with min X (as shown above).

Comment: @Jimi With the 'grid' leaning to left or right as I posted images in my question, max Y and min X won't always give you the bottom left I want. I want it to be the bottom row.

Comment: It's probably the *small screen* I have, I didn't notice an *inclination*, maybe a *shift*  along the Y axis, and/or different sizes. You can invert the result: `return circles.OrderBy(c => c.Center.X).ThenByDescending(c => c.Center.Y).First();`

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea. Will it be correct to say that one circle is bottom-leftier than another, when vector drawn from that circle to another makes angle with X in range (-45, 135) degrees. Then we can determine if angle is correct by calculating scalar product with vector (1, -1).
So we will need to find circle that is bottom-leftier than any other:

```cs
    circles.First(x => circles.All(y => y.Center.X - x.Center.X - (y.Center.Y - x.Center.Y) => 0))
```

Comment: I'm getting "Sequence contains no matching element" sometimes and couldn't figure out why..

Comment: I was afraid of it - that means that for each circle there is one that is bottom-leftier. Can you add picture for failure case?

Comment: Actually I was introducing a "minX" argument to find the bottom left circle of each "group" and that was breaking your logic. I've fixed it now, and it seems to work!